# Find how many pair elements sums up to N

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, array

<sup>Based on a recent [question in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37173914/6188402)</sup>

Write a program/function that takes in one ARRAY/list and returns the number of pair-values which sums up to a given TOTAL.

#### Explaining

```
TOTAL=4, ARRAY=[1,3,7,1,-3] => RESULT=2
```

The result was 2 because `1 + 3` and `7 + -3` are valid pairs which sums up to `TOTAL=4`.

- When one pair is formed, you should not count any of its values again
- Also, you are not allowed to add any value that is not present in the ARRAY.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest in bytes wins

All values will be between your language's int min-max.

#### Another cases

```
9, [1,2,3,5,4,6,7,-10] => 3          // [2,7]  [3,6]  [5,4]
0, [] => 0                           //
0, [1,-2,0,-1,2] => 2                // [1,-1]  [-2,2]
5, [5,5,5,0,-1,1,-5] => 1            // [5,0]
3, [7,-7,8,3,9,1,-1,5] => 0          //
2, [1,1] => 1                        // [1,1]
2, [1,1,1,1,1] => 2                  // [1,1]  [1,1]
4, [1,3,3,3] => 1                    // [1,3]
```

Comment: Why is the result of the third test case 2?

Comment: @Dennis. Because only the pairs: `[1,-1] and [-2,2]` can be formed.

Comment: Why not `[0, 0]`?

Comment: @Dennis. Because `0` occurs only once.

Comment: You don't mention that in the rules. We shouldn't have to infer the rules from the test cases.

Comment: @Dennis. My bad, updating

Comment: I'm unclear about "You shouldn't count duplicates, there was only one 1 for two 3s,...". Does that mean that `4, [1,3,1,3]` should give 2? Can you say exactly what the rules are for duplicates?

Comment: Why does the last test case return 2?

Comment: Oh, it looks like you are looking for the number of **disjoint** pairs of numbers that sum to `n`. When you say "number of pair-values", people usually think of that as the number of choices that can be made, even if they overlap.

Comment: @Dennis. Because you can form `[1,1] and [1,1]` and will remain one `1` alone.. i'm not sure how to write it to you understand

Comment: _When one pair is formed, you should not count any of its values again_ So `4, [1 3 3 3]` should give `1`? I think some of the existing answers would give `3` here

Comment: @LuisMendo. Yes, test case added thanks

Comment: This needs a much clearer spec. All current answers are invalid.

Comment: the answer in [SO linked thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37174127/4571206) isnt pigeon-holes selections.

Comment: @user6188402 do you know atleast that qestion you get inspired from counts intersected pairs?

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
/sM{.cSE2
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2FsM.c%7BE2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=9%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C4%2C6%2C7%2C-10%5D%0A0%0A%5B%5D%0A0%0A%5B1%2C-2%2C0%2C-1%2C2%5D%0A5%0A%5B5%2C5%2C5%2C0%2C-1%2C1%2C-5%5D%0A3%0A%5B7%2C-7%2C8%2C3%2C9%2C1%2C-1%2C5%5D&debug=0&input_size=2)

Takes the number and array newline separated.

**Explanation:**

```
/sM{.cSE2
/sM{.cSE2Q    Implicit variable introduction.
              Implicit: Q = eval(input())
       E      Take the array as input.
      S       Sort the input.
    .c  2     Form all ordered pairs.
   {          Deduplicate.
 sM           Map each to its sum.
/        Q    Count the number of occurrences of Q in the resulting list.
```

Comment: This seems for fail for `2, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` (the challenge was very unclear...)

Answer (score 4):

## R, 48 bytes

```r
function(x,y)sum(colSums(combn(unique(x),2))==y)
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! This is a nice first answer. Functions don't need to be named--we allow unnamed function definitions as submissions--so you can save 2 bytes by removing `f=`. :)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 13 bytes

```
l{SMfqQsT.PE2
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l%7BSMfqQsT.PE2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=4%0A%5B1%2C3%2C7%2C1%2C-3%5D%0A9%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C4%2C6%2C7%2C-10%5D%0A0%0A%5B%5D%0A0%0A%5B1%2C-2%2C0%2C-1%2C2%5D%0A5%0A%5B5%2C5%2C5%2C0%2C-1%2C1%2C-5%5D%0A3%0A%5B7%2C-7%2C8%2C3%2C9%2C1%2C-1%2C5%5D&debug=0&input_size=2).

Answer (score 1):

### Matlab(38)

```
 @(a,b)nnz(sum(nchoosek([b,.5],2)')==a)
```

- the 0.5 part is a dodge for second test case

---

cropped by 2 bytes following Alex' comment.

Comment: Functions don't have to be named; you can just use the `@(a,b)` handle and omit `f=`, saving 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 48 bytes

```
x->n->count(p->sum(p)==n,combinations(∪(x),2))
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts an array and an integer and returns an integer. To call it, assign it to a variable and call like `f(x)(n)`.

We get all combinations of size 2 from the unique values in the input array and for each pair test whether the sum is equal to the input integer. We count all such cases and return the result.

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=Zj14LT5uLT5jb3VudChwLT5zdW0ocCk9PW4sY29tYmluYXRpb25zKOKIqih4KSwyKSkKCmZvciB0ZXN0IGluIFsoOSwgWzEsMiwzLDUsNCw2LDcsLTEwXSwgMyksCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAoMCwgW10sIDApLAogICAgICAgICAgICAgKDAsIFsxLC0yLDAsLTEsMl0sIDIpLAogICAgICAgICAgICAgKDUsIFs1LDUsNSwwLC0xLDEsLTVdLCAxKSwKICAgICAgICAgICAgICgzLCBbNywtNyw4LDMsOSwxLC0xLDVdLCAwKV0KICAgIHByaW50bG4oZih0ZXN0WzJdKSh0ZXN0WzFdKSA9PSB0ZXN0WzNdKQplbmQ&input=) (includes all test cases)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <del>112</del> <del>67</del> <del>59</del> 52 bytes

```
(a,b)=>{c=0;for(i of a)a.map(j=>c+=i+j==b);return c}
```

Because of amazing `for-of` loops of ES6, I was able to shave off **42** bytes from my previous solution!

**Update** : Thanks to @user6188402 for helping me shave off 3 bytes!

**Update** : Thanks to @Bálint for helping me shave off 15 bytes!

[Try it Online!](http://jsbin.com/rewerubixu/edit?js,console)

**Note** : *This fails for repeating numbers.*